# How to restore/resynch Gradle inside IntelliJ?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I have been using Intellij 2018.1 and Gradle for a while now without issues. This is the first time I have seen this problem.

I have a Gradle-based Java project that doesn't seem to behave correctly when I edit the `build.gradle` in IntelliJ. Gradle behaves correctly when I issue commands on the terminal, so I think this is limited to IntelliJ's integration w/ Gradle.

#### What I'm used to seeing in other projects

- When I modify the list of compile-time dependencies inside `build.gradle`, Gradle refreshes and updates the entire dependency graph
- If it can't find a new dependency that I've added, the refresh/rebuild fails and I see errors inside IntelliJ
- If the new dependencies are found, I see them show up under the External Libraries section of the Project window/pane on the left-hand side of the editor
- I also see a `Build` tab at the bottom that seems to log the rebuild/refresh:

[image]

#### What I'm seeing in this one project

- When I modify my compile-time dependencies from inside IntelliJ, nothing runs/rebuilds on the screen to indicate I've made any changes

  - I can run Gradle on the command line and see success/failure as appropriate, but nothing is updated in IntelliJ
- The External Libraries do not update as expected under the Project window
- Furthermore I don't even see that `Build` tab:

[image]

**Any ideas as to what is going wrong and what I can do to restore/fix Gradle for my project?**

Comment: Try to delete .idea directory and reimport the project from build.gradle. If the issue persists, check [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) for errors.

Comment: Interesting, thanks @CrazyCoder (+1) so deleting .idea and reimporting _has_ fixed it...sort of. It now gives me the `Build` tab and allows me to **manually** Refresh the Gradle Project. However editing `build.gradle` dependencies and saving the file *does not* trigger a refresh automatically like it does with other projects. I have to do it manually each time. This will definitely become annoying...any way to tell Gradle to refresh the project each time `build.gradle` is edited? Thanks again!

Comment: Use the [Refresh button](https://i.imgur.com/HLsnENy.png) or enable the [auto-import](https://i.imgur.com/FbQx36A.png).

Comment: Thank you! If you like, turn your comment(s) into a short answer and I'll happily give you the green check :-) thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project was probably not imported from Gradle, but created manually in the IDE using the wizard. You can import it again from `build.gradle` file and overwrite the existing project files.

Changes are refreshed either [manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuVpG.png) or [automatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkwXE.png) depending on your settings.